# Check parent div element contains class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a class inside a div element. This div element is present inside another div element.
 How to check whether the parent div element contains that class. Or
How to traverse from parent div element to the inner div element and check the class?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `>` css selector to check if an element is exactly one level inside another element.

```
var innerDiv = document.querySelector("#parent_div_id > div > .innerClass");

if(innerDiv) { // yes, it exists!
```

[querySelector docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasClass(ele, klassName) {
// First we get the value of the ele's class-attribute with `ele.className`.
// That can return an empty string, or one class-name, or several class-names
// separated by spaces. To regard these cases, we pre- and append spaces, before
// checking for the occurence of the passed `klassName` with `indexOf()`.
  return (' ' + ele.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + klassName + ' ') > -1
}

function firstChildEleHasClass(ele, klassName) {
  ele = ele.firstElementChild
  return hasClass(ele, klassName)
}

function parentEleHasClass(ele, klassName) {
  ele = ele.parentElement
  return hasClass(ele, klassName)
}
```